# Clear APC cache for single domain or directory

Tags: php, apc

On my server I have multiple sites and I have APC configured with `stat = 0`.

Is there a way, when I deploy newer version of code, to clear the APC cache for every file a host or a directory on the server?

Answer (score 1):

You can manipulate and delete single entries via php or the apc admin, but this might get tedious if you have many entries.

So you will be left with the option to delete everything, which is not what you want, I'm guessing.
To only delete the entries of one specific domain, you need to run differen apc instances. This is highly recommende anyway, since you can't guarantuee they don't overwrite each others data otherwise.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that I can run different istances of APC. Thanks